# Validating entered values in DataGridView Cell using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I'm using VB.Net 2008 and trying to validate a certain cell with certain values like:

In DataGridView1 i want to check the entered data in column 1 and cell 1 if it's less than 10 or not so i used the following code

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValidating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValidating

    If DataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
        If DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value < 10 Then
            DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).ErrorText = "Not Less Than 10"
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

The problem is: every time i try to enter any value in this cell it see nothing (Empty Value) unless if it was already has a value before i start to edit it and always use this value regardless of any new value i write

so how do i validate those cells to not allow users to leave this cell unless it get the right value

Note : CellValidated is working perfectly but it has no e.cancel to prevent users from leaving this cell

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but in order to validate the actual value you need to use `DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).FormattedValue`, which will give you the modified value. By using `DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value` you will always get the previous value (uneditted, if the cell is editted for the first time you will get the empty value you see). Note that the FormattedValue works only in the CellValidating method.
Hope this helps anyone who passes by this question. ^^